# How to return an array of grouped items?

Tags: c#, rest, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a simple `GET` request working to return all of my elements. But I can't seem to figure out how to return those elements in a grouped array, *grouped by name and date*.

**My model:**

```cs
public class Event
{
   [Key]
   public long ID { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public DateTime date { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string name { get; set; }
}
```

This is my **GET request** to return all elements:

```cs
[Route("api/events")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Event>>> GetEvents()
{
   return await _context.Events.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the structure you want to produce?

Comment: You can't, with that method signature; it claims the Get will return an enumeration of Event - that's not an array of a grouping of events. A grouping would have (a collection of) an object that cites the group keys  name/date and a collection of the Event values in the group. Best you could do with that signature is to order the events by name/date and the remote end can detect a change from one item to the next and know to start a new group

Comment: Your syntax looks fine. You are defining getter and setter property in your code. To return an element, you need to define a field which is usually private. Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a DTO like this:

```
public class GroupedEventsDto
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // although you already know date and name, 
    // so you could have the list of IDs only
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

and do it simply like:

```
[HttpGet("api/events")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<GroupedEventsDto>>> GetEvents()
{
    var events = await context.Events.ToArrayAsync();

    var data = events 
       .GroupBy(x => new { x.date, x.name })
       .Select(grp => new GroupedEventsDto
       {
          Date = grp.Key.date,
          Name = grp.Key.name,
          Events = grp.ToList()
        })
        .ToList();

    return data;
}
```

This would generate a JSON like

```
[
    {
        "Name": "a",
        "Date": "2020-08-22",
        "Events": [
            {
                "Name": "a",
                "Date": "2020-08-22",
                "Id": 1
            }, ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "b",
        "Date": "2020-08-22",
        "Events": [
            {
                "Name": "b",
                "Date": "2020-08-22",
                "Id": 2
            }, ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Of course, which properties you end up needing would change in `GroupedEventsDto`

Comment: Hey, when I tried your code, it says: `The name X doesn't exist in current context`

Comment: @zalias Small typo, fixed

Comment: Thought the same, but now I'm getting a different kind of error: `cannot await 'method group'`

Comment: @zalias I'm not good today it seems :) there was a missing `)`

Comment: Now it did compile thanks! But when trying to call /api/events im getting 500 status error: [link](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/D2wrFJY5hV/)

Comment: @zalias Sorry, I haven't worked on the latest versions of EF Core. Let me do this in VS and update the answer. Up to EF Core 2.x this worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220261/discussion-between-zalias-and-camilo-terevinto).